# Navigation instructions

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, navigation

i'm trying to create a navigation for my app. I have made the call to google, i have the json with all the info inside.

My problem is how to make my app give the order to the user for turning left in the corner. Should i use the start_location":

```
 {
                "lat": 37.9836664,
                "lng": 23.7541535
```

from google response?

how do i know if it is too early or too late?

Also if i compare all the time my current location with the start_Location i need to say turn left whouln't make my app really slow??

Answer (score 0):

You should get the bearing between two locations to provide directions to the user

Comment: why ?? The google api gives me the distance and the lat/long.Why should i get the bearing?? How does the bearing will help me tell the user to rutn left to a specific corner?

Comment: Use the bearing angle to rotate the icon/marker which you are using to show the directions